# $\int_{-1}^{1} x^{k+i} P_n(x)dx$, $P_n$ Legendre polynomial.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, special-functions

I was wondering whether there is a way to say what $$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{k} P_n(x)dx$$ is, where $k,n$ are positive integers or zero and $P_n$ is the n-th Legendre polynomial? I am looking for an analytic result for this.

Probably one could use this: Barne's integral: [Barne's Integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.17#ii)

But the set over which is integrated is different in this case.

Comment: Please make titles informative.

Comment: Can't you just use integration parts?

Comment: @Lipschitz Difficulty is subjective. Make titles as objective possible.

Comment: @Lipschitz But have you actually tried using integration by parts? The boundary terms should vanish so I don't think it'll be a long expression. Also, what is the point of having $k$ and $i$? It seems like the $i$ and $k$ themselves play absolutely no role, but their sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consider
$$I(m,n)=\int_{-1}^{1}x^m P_n(x)dx\tag{1}$$

Since $x^{m}$ belongs to the linear span of $P_0(x),\ldots, P_{m}(x)$, the orthogonality implies that for $m<n$ the integral vanishes. Also, it can be easily inferred from parity that $I(m,n)=0$ if $m+n$ is odd.
Therefore we assume henceforth that $m\geq n$ and $m+n$ is even.

Now let us use the [Rodrigues formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula)
$$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n\right]$$
to integrate $n$ times by parts in (1). This yields
$$I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2^n} {m \choose n} \int_{-1}^{1}x^{m-n}\left(1-x^2\right)^n dx.\tag{2}$$ 
Since $m-n$ is even by assumption, we can make the change of variables $t=x^2$, which reduces (2) to a beta function integral, with the final result
$$I(m,n)=\frac{1}{2^{n}} {m \choose n}B\left(\frac{m-n+1}2,n+1\right)=2^{n+1} \frac{m!\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\right)!}{(m+n+1)!\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\right)!}$$